# Custom user model breaks auth tests

Tags: django, testing, fixtures, authentication

Hecko out there,

I’m using a custom user model that I’ve opted to call Member, which extends the default user model (pretty much as described [here](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/)).

The rub is that this breaks several tests of the auth app, because the test fixture only creates standard *users*, not *members*. When I add the missing *member* definitions/rows to django/contrib/auth/fixtures/authtestdata.json they run again, but that’s of course no solution.

Is this is a result of me doing something wrong, and how should I best go about fixing it?

As a last recourse, I would just add a patch for authtestdata.json in Buildout, but perhaps there is a more elegant solution.

Thanks a lot,
Telofy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Please disregard my post below. Use [the original version](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/) of the custom auth backend and add `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` as a second (fallback) backend under the custom one in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in your `settings.py`. It has the same effect and is much simpler.

---

I now got rid of the patch and instead extended the [custom auth backend](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/) that I linked to in my question to fall back on the methods of the original auth backend if the user can’t be found in the member table (my custom user). If this happens, a warning is issued (which can be a bit annoying when running the tests). Also, the messages tests cause a lot of exceptions, but they don’t seem to have any adverse effect on the tests. I hope they are intentional. ^^

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import logging
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.db.models import get_model

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/
class CustomUserModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = self.user_class.objects.get(username=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except self.user_class.DoesNotExist:
            user = super(CustomUserModelBackend, self).authenticate(username, password)
            if user:
                logger.warn("Using User, not Member: %s" % user)
            return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return self.user_class.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except self.user_class.DoesNotExist:
            user = super(CustomUserModelBackend, self).get_user(user_id)
            if user:
                logger.warn("Using User, not Member: %s" % user)
            return user

    @property
    def user_class(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_user_class'):
            self._user_class = get_model(*settings.CUSTOM_USER_MODEL.split('.', 2))
            if not self._user_class:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured('Could not get custom user model')
        return self._user_class
```

Answer (score 1):

You may get some joy from setting the AUTH_USER_PROFILE parameter in settings.py, as per http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users. This is a great way of extending the standard User model in a way that Django can work with.

Comment: Thanks, but I decided against that at some point. We store information about users that are equally (perhaps even more) fundamental than their name; separating those fields out into a profile seemed very unintuitive. Subclassing models has worked since 2008-04-26, and this seems like a textbook use case for inheritance. If more problems should surface, I’ll reconsider, but so far I prefer my hacky patch.